# How to drop groups if their time appearance exceeds 300 secs?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns: ch_name, time, values, and intervals. I put this dataframe to "for" loop, so it groups data by ch_name. Dataframe "time" values for all channel start with DD:MM:YYYY 00:00:00 (always).I want to drop groups if their "time" column values more than 300 secs. So I do not want to see groups if their time starts, for example, 00:01:15 or 11:32:05 and so on. It must keep groups with 00:00:00 date.

```
[1439 rows x 4 columns]
                              ch_name                time    value  interval
0     LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 00:01:00  23028.0      60.0
1     LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 00:02:00  23028.0      60.0
2     LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 00:03:00  23028.0      60.0
3     LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 00:04:00  23028.0      60.0
4     LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 00:05:00  23028.0      60.0
...                               ...                 ...      ...       ...
1434  LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 23:55:00  23116.0      60.0
1435  LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 23:56:00  23116.0      60.0
1436  LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 23:57:00  23116.0      60.0
1437  LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 23:58:00  23116.0      60.0
1438  LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count 2019-09-19 23:59:00  23117.0      60.0

[1439 rows x 4 columns]
              ch_name                time   value  interval
0     LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 00:01:00  1015.0      60.0
1     LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 00:02:00  1015.0      60.0
2     LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 00:03:00  1015.0      60.0
3     LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 00:04:00  1015.0      60.0
4     LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 00:05:00  1015.0      60.0
...               ...                 ...     ...       ...
1434  LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 23:55:00  1015.0      60.0
1435  LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 23:56:00  1015.0      60.0
1436  LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 23:57:00  1015.0      60.0
1437  LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 23:58:00  1015.0      60.0
1438  LIN.Cold_Resets 2019-09-19 23:59:00  1015.0      60.0

[1439 rows x 4 columns]
                         ch_name                time      value  interval
0   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:20:00   9.800000      60.0
1   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:21:00  13.800000      60.0
2   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:22:00  15.933333      60.0
3   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:23:00  17.600000      60.0
4   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:24:00  19.000000      60.0
5   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:25:00  20.066667      60.0
6   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:26:00  21.133333      60.0
7   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:27:00  22.133333      60.0
8   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:28:00  23.000000      60.0
9   Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:29:00  23.866667      60.0
10  Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:30:00  24.666667      60.0
11  Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:31:00  25.466667      60.0
12  Payload.PAX_Temperature_degC 2019-09-19 11:32:00  25.800000      60.0
                               ch_name                time     value  interval
0   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:20:00  1.600000      60.0
1   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:21:00  1.600000      60.0
2   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:22:00  1.600000      60.0
3   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:23:00  1.600000      60.0
4   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:24:00  1.600000      60.0
5   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:25:00  1.600000      60.0
6   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:26:00  1.600000      60.0
7   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:27:00  1.597167      60.0
8   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:28:00  1.583000      60.0
9   Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:29:00  1.583000      60.0
10  Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:30:00  1.588667      60.0
11  Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:31:00  1.597167      60.0
12  Payload.X-band_TX-0_SW13_Current_A 2019-09-19 11:32:00  1.600000      60.0
```

So, I do not need last 2 groups, because channels appeared at 11:20:00. Thanks

Comment: The first two groups have times that appear beyond 300 seconds.  So do you actually want to filter your data for everything below 300 seconds?

Comment: @manwithfewneeds that channels updating properly, it means that 2 first channel groups has an information between 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. last 2 groups appeared only once and its information only 12 minutes. so information is not full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the min time per channel, then select all channels where min time is less then specified threshold (300 s = 5 min = datetime.time(0,5,0) in the example)

```
import datetime
grp = df.groupby('ch_name').time.min().dt.time
df = df[df.ch_name.isin(grp[grp <= datetime.time(0,5,0)].index)]
```

**Update for max time:**

After filtering for min do the same for max:

```
grp = df.groupby('ch_name').time.max().dt.time
df = df[df.ch_name.isin(grp[grp >= datetime.time(23,55,0)].index)]
```

Comment: How can I make it for the max time?  For  example, If data's initial time starts at 00:00:01 but finishes at 23:57:00 or 23:58:00 which is not acceptable. NOTE: as a max time I have 00:00:00 and 23:59:00

Comment: Please see my updated answer (adjust the threshold time as needed). If you know in advance that your entries are in equal intervals (say 60 secs), you could also filter on the number of rows per group (1440 per day if all exist, take the group if it contains say min 1430 rows) with [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html).

Comment: Updated max time removes data wit time 00:00:00, because it is max time.:((

Comment: You mean that `2019-09-19 00:00:00` comes **after** `2019-09-19 23:59:00` (doesn't seem to make much sense)? Or do you mean that the **last** entry for a given channel after `2019-09-19 23:59:00` is `2019-09-20 00:00:00`?

Comment: last entry for a given channel after 2019-09-19 23:59:00 is 2019-09-20 00:00:00

Comment: OK, in this case you can add a new column `df['time_new']=df.time + pd.offsets.Minute(-1)` and replace column `time` with `time_new` in the code of the answer.

Comment: After final result I have sometimes 1439 and 1440 rows. If dataframe has 1439 rows how can I fill it with last data to equal it ti 1440? Do you have any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can, as a final step, group by date and [upsample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) by `'T'` (1 min). You can specify how to fill the new rows. It might be necessary to move the time to the index though (not sure). I think it's better to post this as a separate question.